# 'API_KEY' is defined but never used 'CONTEXT_KEY' is assigned a value but never used

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a file called `keys.js`, where it houses my `API_KEY`. I've exported it from that file and imported it into my `useGoogleSearch.js` file. However, it's not properly importing and my error keeps returning as `"'API_KEY' is defined but never used 'CONTEXT_KEY' is assigned a value but never used Unexpected template string expression"`.

I think it has to do with my url -  `'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?  key=${API_KEY}&cx=${CONTEXT_KEY}&q=${term}'`.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import API_KEY from "./keys";

const CONTEXT_KEY = "ANOTHER KEY";

const useGoogleSearch = (term) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async() => {
            fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&cx=${CONTEXT_KEY}&q=${term}')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(result => {
                    setData(result)
                })
         }

        fetchData();
     }, [term])

     return { data };
};

export default useGoogleSearch
```

Comment: You've code the string literal `"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&cx=${CONTEXT_KEY}&q=${term}"` instead of a templated string, `\`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&cx=${CONTEXT_KEY}&q=${term}\``.

Comment: Awesome. This helped immensely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your API URL as a string here.

```
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&cx=${CONTEXT_KEY}&q=${term}')
```

So your variables `API_KEY` and `CONTEXT_KEY` are not evaluated as values. Instead, use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&cx=${CONTEXT_KEY}&q=${term}`)
```